# error when trying to clone a postgres database (pg_dump, pg_restore)

Tags: postgresql, docker, pg-dump

I am trying to clone a database from one postgres to another.  I am using an old version of postgres 8.1.4 the new database is inside an docker container running ubuntu.

I'll need to copy the full db but for simplicity now I am showing the error on a single table.
On the currently populated server I do:

`pg_dump -U postgres -d cnx -t freq1_data -F c > /data/misc/luca/freq1_data.dump` in order to dump the table.

then  I create the container with the following dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install python3.8 -y
RUN apt-get install python3.8-venv -y
RUN apt-get install python3.8-distutils -y
RUN apt-get install python3.8-venv python3.8-dev -y

RUN apt-get install gcc -y

RUN mkdir adam
ADD /adam/ /adam/
RUN mkdir /cnx_data/


RUN python3.8 -m venv adam_env
RUN /bin/bash -c "source /adam_env/bin/activate"
RUN ./adam_env/bin/pip install -r /adam/build/requirements.txt
RUN ./adam_env/bin/pip install -e /adam/src/adam/



RUN apt-get install build-essential -y
RUN apt-get install wget -y
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential libreadline-dev zlib1g-dev flex bison libxml2-dev libxslt-dev libssl-dev
RUN apt-get install -y clang

RUN wget https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v8.1.4/postgresql-8.1.4.tar.gz
RUN tar -xzf postgresql-8.1.4.tar.gz
RUN apt-get install libreadline-dev -y
RUN cd postgresql-8.1.4 && ./configure CFLAGS="-O2" CC=clang && make && make install

RUN mkdir /usr/local/pgsql/data
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash postgres
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/pgsql/data/
RUN mkdir /usr/local/pgsql/log
RUN chown -R postgres /usr/local/pgsql/ 

USER postgres
RUN /usr/local/pgsql/bin/initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data

COPY freq1_data.dump /cnx_data/
```

From a running container I do:

```
postgres@c1ee3cfe5dbf:/$ /usr/local/pgsql/bin/postmaster -D /usr/local/pgsql/data & 
[1] 10
postgres@c1ee3cfe5dbf:/$ LOG:  could not bind IPv6 socket: Cannot assign requested address
HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-04-01 18:14:57 UTC
LOG:  checkpoint record is at 0/38FF90
LOG:  redo record is at 0/38FF90; undo record is at 0/0; shutdown TRUE
LOG:  next transaction ID: 565; next OID: 10794
LOG:  next MultiXactId: 1; next MultiXactOffset: 0
LOG:  database system is ready
LOG:  transaction ID wrap limit is 2147484146, limited by database "postgres"

postgres@c1ee3cfe5dbf:/$ /usr/local/pgsql/bin/createdb -T template0 cnx
LOG:  transaction ID wrap limit is 2147484146, limited by database "postgres"
CREATE DATABASE
postgres@c1ee3cfe5dbf:/$ 
postgres@c1ee3cfe5dbf:/$ /usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_restore -U postgres -d cnx /cnx_data/freq1_data.dump
```

this last command returns a large number of errors:

```
    postgres@c1ee3cfe5dbf:/$ cat /tmp/error.log | head                                                                                                                                   
pg_restore: [archiver] Error while PROCESSING TOC:                                                                                                                                   
pg_restore: [archiver] Error from TOC entry 2439; 1259 2506496895 TABLE freq1_data postgres                                                                                          
pg_restore: [archiver] could not set search_path to "smdata": ERROR:  schema "smdata" does not exist                                                                                 
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "freq1_data_id_seq" does not exist                                                                             
    Command was:                                                                                                                                                                     
CREATE TABLE freq1_data (                                                                                                                                                            
    id integer DEFAULT nextval('freq1_data_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,                                                                                                              
    measurement_point_id ...
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "freq1_data" does not exist
    Command was: ALTER TABLE ONLY freq1_data ALTER COLUMN cbdist_pkt_queue SET STORAGE EXTERNAL;
postgres@c1ee3cfe5dbf:/$ cat /tmp/error.log | head -n 20
pg_restore: [archiver] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver] Error from TOC entry 2439; 1259 2506496895 TABLE freq1_data postgres
pg_restore: [archiver] could not set search_path to "smdata": ERROR:  schema "smdata" does not exist
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "freq1_data_id_seq" does not exist
    Command was: 
CREATE TABLE freq1_data (
    id integer DEFAULT nextval('freq1_data_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
    measurement_point_id ...
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "freq1_data" does not exist
    Command was: ALTER TABLE ONLY freq1_data ALTER COLUMN cbdist_pkt_queue SET STORAGE EXTERNAL;
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "freq1_data" does not exist
```

I feel like I am missing something. Like defining a schema but I am not able to understand what to do.

**EDIT 1:**
After running: `create schema smdata`

I get as error:

```
postgres@323cadf989cf:/$ cat /tmp/error.log | head
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2439; 1259 2506496895 TABLE freq1_data postgres
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "freq1_data_id_seq" does not exist
    Command was: 
CREATE TABLE freq1_data (
    id integer DEFAULT nextval('freq1_data_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
    measurement_point_id ...
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "freq1_data" does not exist
    Command was: ALTER TABLE ONLY freq1_data ALTER COLUMN cbdist_pkt_queue SET STORAGE EXTERNAL;
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "freq1_data" does not exist
postgres@323cadf989cf:/$
```

It seems like it did not copy the schema from the old db.

Comment: Is there any other error displayed by pg_restore *before* `relation  "freq1_data" does not exist"` ?

Comment: sorry I have updated the error message. It contains extra information now

Comment: Try to run `create schema smdata` in cnx database before running pg_restore.

Comment: I have added the result at the end of the question. It looks like it is not copying the schema

Comment: Note that if you have run pg_dump -t freq1_data you have exported only the table freq1_data and you can only import what you have exported. Creating the schema with `create schema' creates just the logical container without any object. Postgresql 8.4 is quite old. It is not clear why CREATE TABLE fails. It could be easier to simply export the database cnx and to import it.

Comment: I'll try again with the full cnx db but it was failing with similar errors. It will take a while I'll update the question as soon as I have results

Comment: I am testing with PG 8.4.22 and I note that pg_dump 8.4.22 has no "-d" option. Are you sure you are using the right version of pg_dump ?

Comment: The error I'm seeing `relation "freq1_data_id_seq" does not exist` means you are using that sequence for auto increment IDs in `freq1_data`; you need to create the sequence as well.

Comment: the use of `-d` could be an error as `-d, --inserts            dump data as INSERT, rather than COPY, commands `.

Comment: OK as already said try to create the sequence with `create sequence smdata.freq1_data_id_seq;`. But I can reproduce your pg_dump command only with `pg_dump -t smdata.freq1_data -F c cnx > freq1_data.dump` : i.e you need to give prefix table name with schema name and database name is given without any option.

Comment: I think the right way to use it was `pg_dump -U postgres  -F c -c -f /data/misc/luca/cnx.dump cnx`.  It'll take a while to generate the results. this could be the cause of the error

Comment: `-c` (--clean) is only meaningful for the plain-text format. For archive formats (-Fc) you can specify it when using pg_restore.

Answer (score 0):

You should dump the sequence as well:

```sh
pg_dump -U postgres -t freq1_data_id_seq -t freq1_data -F c -f /data/misc/luca/freq1_data.dump cnx
```

And **always** use `pg_dump` from the later PostgreSQL version, not from 8.1.